# Search in titles of audio files

Tags: windows-7, windows, audio, windows-search

I've many audio files which I want to search in "Name" and "Title" and "Album" tags.

windows search bar searches the file names but is there any way to search the title and album tags?

Comment: Have you got search indexing of file contents enabled for the folder containing the music?

Comment: yes,"in indexed locations search file names and contents" is ticked

Answer (score 3):

Since you specifically asked for Windows Search, you could use [Advanced Query Syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa965711(v=vs.85).aspx).
The general syntax for your case would be

```
kind:music artist:"my artist" title:"my title"
```

#### Search in action

Note how the title and artist matches, but not the filename itself

[[image]

<sup>Click to enlarge</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MTjXg.png)

#### More properties

```
bitrate, artist, duration, album, genre, track, year
fileext, title, date, modified, folder
```

**Note:** If you're on a localized Windows, the name of these properties also change

Answer (score 1):

I think you would better use Windows Media Player for this kind of searches.
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/how-do-i-perform-advanced-searches-in-windows-media-player

> **Find a specific song, album, or artist:**
>   To search for a specific song, album, or artist, type one or more words in the search box. For example, to find all song titles, album titles, and artist names that contain the word "Prince," type Prince in the search box.
>
> Note that if you type a four-digit number by itself in the search box, the Player will search for songs and albums that were released in that year in addition to songs and album titles containing that number. To narrow the search results for a song or album title that contains a four-digit number, such as the Prince song "1999," include one or more additional words in your search query. For example, to find the Prince song "1999," type 1999 Prince in the search box.

After opening Windows Media Player go to `Organize`->`Manage Libraries`->`Music` Then Click `Add...` then select the folder containing your music files and after that you will see that your music files are being appeared. Then start searching.

Comment: there is no item for "content" to search!!!

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning, check out the new.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use the [foobar2000](http://www.foobar2000.org/) music player.

Albeit being a Music Player, foobar2000 has powerful library management features.

For your specific use case, you could add your Music folders to foobar's library, then go to menu

```
Library -> Album List
```

And in the filter window you can type any text and foobar will search in all tags and filenames.

If you want to be more specific, you can use the [foobar's Query Syntax](http://wiki.hydrogenaud.io/?title=Foobar2000:Query_syntax):

```
(ARTIST HAS Saurom AND TITLE HAS "Romance de la Luna") OR ALBUM IS Maryam
```